# Access with ssh only password without publickey with virtualbox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, ssh-keys, public-key, rsa

I tried to setup the ssh-server without publickey ,
with openssh-server 6.7p1-5

changed sshd_config

```
RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Restart ssh service

from the client side :

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no  test@127.0.0.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/leggenda/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'test'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:mWc3EWaFDUzSjUjmhVvgNibVFgzWHnowAIXNAbApgJ8
The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:mWc3EWaFDUzSjUjmhVvgNibVFgzWHnowAIXNAbApgJ8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
test@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
test@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
test@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Public key authentication is much more secure than password authentication.

Comment: testing environment virtualbox, also if I want to push the id_rsa.pub using ssh-copy-id show the same message

Answer (score 1):

found here the answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/trying-to-ssh-to-local-vm-ubuntu-with-putty

on my local machine the ssh server is running so the port is overlap with my VM so need to change on the setting port forwarding different from 22 example 2222 and then access to it 
ssh -p 2222 username@vm1-ip

Comment: It's a good idea to always run SSH on an alternate port, especially if it's reachable from the outside.  Partly as a security measure, but mostly to keep the log spam (from dictionary attacks) to a minimum.